# Clarification with recursion in java

Tags: java, recursion

So this entire time I thought that my issue with recursion was understanding cases. It turns out that my problem is understanding the values of recursive cases. For example, printing a portion of an array backwards.

Original try

```
    public static void printBackwards(int i, int j, char[] A){
        if(i == j){
            System.out.println(A[i]); 
        }
        else{
            printBackwards(i+1,j,A);
        }

    }
```

A working attempt

```
    public static boolean printBackwards(int i, int j, char[] A){
    if(i == j){
            System.out.println(A[i]);
            return true;
    }
    else{
            if(printBackwards(i+1,j,A) == true){
                System.out.println(A[i]);
                return true;
            }
            else{
                printBackwards(i+1,j,A);
            }
    }
    return false;
    }
```

However, is this even efficient recursion? Or is there a better way through it? This is the only way I could figure out when I looked it it from writing it out.

Comment: "Play computer" with a pencil and paper: toughing it out is the absolute best way to internalize it. Write down values for each call. Indent each level.

Comment: I have tried this, I don't understand the stack in recursion I guess. I'll work on it some more. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Theres a good recursion example here http://learn-java-by-example.com/2010/java/fibonnaci-number

Comment: Fundamentally, the issue is that your recursive method is choosing to do either the recursive call or the print. It needs to do both. The trick is knowing when to print.

Comment: @ object That helps, still having some trouble with this one though. Let me try to grind through it some more. @ dcbyers I see that, that is what I am having trouble working on and visualizing in the stack I guess.

Comment: Why using recursion? Why don't use loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my opinion, to solve this problem doesn't need to use recursion. You can just do it with simple loop.

```
public class PrintBackwards {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] a = new char[] {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'};

        for(int i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any reason behind this why you use recursion? If not, more faster to do it like example above.

If you want to use recursion, I hope this example can make you understand easier than yours.

```
public class PrintBackwards {

    private static char[] a = new char[]{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printBackwards(0);
    }

    public static void printBackwards(int i) {
        if (i < a.length) {
            printBackwards(++i);
            System.out.println(a[i - 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know it could be done with a loop, just wanting to practice recursion and this was an example that came up in class last semester. Your recursion example does help me a lot, writing that out makes complete sense to me. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Start by asking "When can I solve the problem right away (w/o a recursive call)?".  In this case, it would be when the area has only one element -- that's your base case.

When that ISN'T true, you need to break the problem into making a smaller version (which can be solved by calling printBackwards) and whatever remains to completing the problem.  You already have a call that will print A[i+1..j] (for the original value of i).  Thus, all that remains is to print A[i].  Figure out if it should be printed before or after the rest of the array, and you're all set.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Java code to print array in reverse order:

```
public class TestProgram {

    private int[] a = {4, 2, 7, 1, 9, 5, 8};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestProgram p = new TestProgram();
        p.print(a.length - 1);
    }

    public void print(int i) {
        // the anchor of the recursive method
        // it indicates that we are done printing array
        if (i < 0) 
            return;

        // print the current value
        System.out.printf("%d ", a[i]);

        // recursively call print() method
        print(i - 1);
    }
}
```